# PHP url rewrite doesnt happen even if I have configured in htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have added .htaccess file inside my PHP project folder with the below content,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

But when I try to access /project/enviroment if gives me a 404 page. and it doesnt refer the environment.php file internally. Is there any other configurations that I need to do? 
 Thank you.

Comment: This code and comment were posted in one of the answers by me :) Where is this .htaccess located and what is full URL you are using?

Comment: its located inside the project root folder which is lrballot. 
the URL im trying to access is 
localhost/lrballot/project/enviroment

Comment: Have a read on what [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) does.

Comment: Comment out RewriteBase line and retest